# Reconstructing a value from an array of bits

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have an array of bits (stored as Boolean) that I want to reconstruct into an integer. I want to insert bits from the right hand side and shift them left for every bit in my array.

How do I insert a bit at the LSB side and shift it over at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
bool yourarray[32];
int output = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    // Shift the bits left by 1. The first time through the loop this
    // will have no real effect since 0 << 1 == 0.
    output <<= 1;

    // If this particular bit is "on", activate the LSB using a bitwise-or
    if(yourarray[i] == true)
        output |= 1; // this turns on the LSB

    // We could also do this for completeness, but it has no effect since
    // the LSB is already 0:
    else
        output &= ~1; // this turns off the LSB
}
```

I'm assuming an int of size 32 here.

There are other considerations to take into account, like [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) but this should give you an idea. Also beware of signing issues, since in this case the highest (left-most) bit will affect whether the int comes out positive or negative.

Comment: I love you guys, 5 mins into asking a question and theres already a quality answer. Could you comment the code so that it explains exactly what each line does, i don't understand what is happening in the 7 and 9th lines (don't understand the syntax and I can't google those characters). Thanks!

Comment: or `output = output << 1 | yourarray[i];`, insert parens if desired.

Comment: Thanks, actually the data stream is a bit weird, it comes LSB first and is only 24 bits (but the int is 32, so I'll have to manually deal with the 2's complement). Thanks, now I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to give a bit of explanation on what's happening when you use bitwise operators.

Let's say we have a 1 byte (8 bits) value: val1 = 00000011. And we have another 1 byte value: val2 =00100001

If we shift the bits of val1 to the left 2, like so:

```
val1 = val1 << 2;
```

val1 now looks like this: 00001100.

Then, if we OR (|) val2 with val1 like this:

```
val1 = val1 | val2
```

val1 will look like this: 00101101.

I hope this helps ^_^